# Remove only rows whose particular field is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

In my DataTable, I want to remove the rows that have a particular field empty when the user clicks the order icon of that column.

In this example, I want to remove 'John' and order the column when the user clicks "City":

```
Name Sirname Gender City
Nick   S.      M    Rome
John   R.      M    
Mary   D.      F    London
```

This code works, but only if I click twice the DataTable's order icon. The first hit, orders the column, the second one removes the rows.

```
var table = $('#datatable').DataTable();
$('#datatable').on( 'order.dt', function () {
    var order = table.order();
    var data = table.rows().data(); 

    if (order[0][0]== 3){
        if(data[0][3] == ''){
            table.row().remove().draw();
        }
    }
});
```

How can I remove the fired rows and order the column with a single click?

Comment: I have no issue when I try your code. The rows are removed when I order the column "*City*", even for the first time.

Comment: @Massimiliano : Are those records supposed to be removed permanently?

Comment: in my case it doesn't remove anything neither at second click, nor at third or fourth and it looks like (from your code) it is not supposed to

Comment: @user11299053 - Yes. If you order that column and there are many empty city fields, you probably had to browse several pages to view rows with that field filled in.

Comment: @Massimiliano : The solution, I have shared below, works for entire table (through all pages). Have you checked that out? If it works for you, upvote and accept are appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need entries with empty field `city` to get permanently removed upon clicking `City` column header, I would suggest the following solution:

```js
const srcData = [
  {name: 'Nick', surname: 'S.', gender: 'M', city: 'Rome'},
  {name: 'John', surname: 'R.', gender: 'M', city: ''},
  {name: 'Mary', surname: 'D.', gender: 'F', city: 'London'},
  {name: 'George', surname: 'K.', gender: 'M', city: ''}
];

$('#mytable').DataTable({
  dom: 't',
  data: srcData,
  columns: ['name', 'surname', 'gender', 'city'].map(header => ({title: header, data: header}))
});

$('thead th').unbind('click').on('click', function(e){
  //grab the table and column being affected
  const table = $(this).closest('table').DataTable();
  const column = table.column($(this));
  //define sort order to set (default 'asc')
  const sortingOrder = $(this).hasClass('sorting_asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';
  //remove entries where 'city' is empty if 4-th column is clicked
  if(column.index() == 3) {
    //get an array of indexes of 'bad' rows
    const badRows = [];
    table.rows().every(function(rowIndex){
      if(this.data().city == '') badRows.push(rowIndex);
    });
    //get those badRows removed
    table.rows(badRows).remove();
  }
  //do default action - sort table
  table.order([column.index(), sortingOrder]).draw();
}).on('mousedown', e => e.preventDefault());
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<table id="mytable"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Woops, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'city' of undefined`.

Comment: Yeah, I see (I suddenly figured out, I didn't click 'City' column first thing while testing). I'm getting it fixed.

Comment: @U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg: thank you! I'll try your suggestion in my environment.

Comment: @U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg: I have my datatable filled dynamically by ruby with data from a db. The jquery script that activate the datatables is common to several pages of my app. How can I convert your code to work in my environment, (i.e. grabbing data from column "city", which is actually named "new city", without create the vars srcData and columns)?

Comment: In order to have your DataTable sourced dynamically, you may employ [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) option. Your server-side script should respond with array of objects (similar by its structure to my `srcData` variable). Option `columns` can be set dynamically either (you can modify that from within `ajax` success callback).

Comment: However, essential part (filter button click handler) will work regardless of the way you feed DataTable with data, the only thing you need to bear in mind is that if your source data is array of arrays or HTML (which I wouldn't suggest to do), you may need to refer to `city` (or `new city`, whatever) part of your row data by column index (`[3]`), rather than `.city`.